# termios ioctl error on ssh subsystem

Tags: python, openssh

I'm using the following code to read/write to stdin/stdout:

```
def _receive_message(self):
    msg = ''
    stdin_fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old = tty.tcgetattr(stdin_fd)
    tty.setcbreak(stdin_fd)

    while True:
        msg = msg + sys.stdin.read(1)
        if msg.endswith("]]>]]>"):
            return msg[:-6]
            sys.stdout.flush()
            tty.tcsetattr(stdin_fd, tty.TCSAFLUSH, old)
def send_message(self, msg):
    print(msg)
```

on 2 modes:

1. ssh
2. ssh -s netconf

both starting running the same python code.
with the first method it works fine,
with the second I receive
    closing connection due to exception (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
as I read the error is because the code is not running in a terminal environment, thus missing terminal settings.
How can I make them run in the same way?

Edit:
The ssh connection is donde with open ssh,
sshd_config handles the netconf subsystem with:
    Subsystem netconf /bin/bash /home/user/.netconf_login
.netconf_login is the same as /home/user/.bash_login:

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT="${SSH_CLIENT##* }"
source /home/scripts/common_env_variables.sh

if [ "$PORT" -eq 830 ]; then
    sudo MIBDIRS=$MIBDIRS USER=$USER ROLE=$ROLE /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/netconf_server.py
fi
exit
```

Comment: It looks like the code that you posted is working on an already established SSH connection. Please [edit] your question to include the code for opening the SSH session to the remote system and invoking the remote command.